# Tkinter- Option Menu

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

There's probably a simple answer to this but I'm not sure what to look up. I'm coding a drop down menu with values 0-10 like this:

```
var1 = IntVar()
ar1.set("0")
self.federalWithholding = OptionMenu(self, var1, "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
```

Is there a way to have those values be integers instead of strings?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to do. Possibly because I don't know `tkinter.OptionMenu` very well. To make those integers instead of strings, just remove the `"` marks. To make them WORK as integers instead of strings is probably impossible. Why do you need this?

Comment: Whatever value they choose will be used in a formula so strings won't work. I tried removing the "" and got the same error. unsupported operand types 'instance' and 'float'

Comment: but `IntVar.get()` always returns an integer. This shouldn't break anything at all.

Comment: If you're getting the error `unsupported operand types 'instance' and 'float'`, does that mean you're later doing `12.5 + var1` (or whatever)? If you're getting the SAME error, this is indicative of something else. `IntVar` is a wrapper for a value, not a value itself. Replace all copies of `var1` in your formulas with `var1.get()` and it should work.

Comment: Classic XY problem. Looks like the issue is an incorrect implementation of `IntVar` not one of `OptionMenu`.

Comment: Actually I had it with federalWithholding. Got it now, thanks.